# Are shared_ptr and the reference counting in iOS the same idea?

Tags: c++, ios, boost

I'm not very experienced with either C++ or iOS, so I'm just curious if iOS the reference counting works basically alike in boost shared pointers and in NSObject?

Comment: I *think* that ARC (iOS' new refcount implementation) is strict enough on a language level to prevent, or at least render difficult, introducing circular reference problems.  boost::shared_ptr has no protection against circular references to my knowledge.  Otherwise, I would expect that you could anticipate very similar semantics and performance out of both.

Comment: ARC does not prevent circular references in any way.

Comment: From some google search: "Using ARC in your own projects is extremely simple. You keep programming as usual, except that you no longer call retain, release and autorelease. That’s basically all there is to it.". This means two things: that 1) yes, this is some form of RAII, like `shared_ptr` provides, 2) that previous development in this platform was error prone. At first sight, from what I gather, I prefer the unique_ptr/shared_ptr mechanism for its clarity ([link here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gather [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/ios-5-automatic-reference-counting-arc), using ARC is very similar to using `std::shared_ptr` ("strong" pointers) and `std::weak_ptr` ("weak" pointers).

Abuse the former, and avoid the latter. Anyway, prefer `std::unique_ptr` if you can.

*(Also, I am somewhat astonished that you had to release pointers manually when programming for iOS. In the 21st century.)*

Comment: I personally hate automatic memory management and more than happy with Obj-C memory management model. I want to have full control over when objects created and released and I see nothing difficult in releasing object when you no longer need it.

Comment: Don't know about all C-derivative languages (are there many of them actually?), but we're talking about reference counting in Obj-C now. Developers nowadays became too lazy even to think and write simple [obj release], they want everything to happen automatically.

Comment: @mifki: My personal rant about manual memory management in C++ is that it is not exception safe: when you do acquire-consume-release, an exception may pop up in consume, in which case you want to have the resource released automatically. If you manage errors manually, like you do in C, there is nothing particularly wrong with manual memory management. It is just less convenient. Also the RAII pattern is the heart of C++, and you can use it to manage way more stuff than memory (managing locks, files, a transformation stack in an OpenGL application, etc)

Comment: @AlexandreC. In Obj-C exceptions are almost not used and also there's such thing as autorelease pool that will release most of the objects when exception is catched (at the end of event processing loop iteration).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced with C++ so I may be not completely correct about shared_ptr, but for me they doesn't seem alike. In Obj-C there're two options. Manual memory management - you manually increment and decrement reference counts for your objects, no magic occurs here. And new ARC which is mostly compile-time feature, while shared_ptr is just runtime implementation.

Comment: shared_ptr is compile time too. The counter may (or may not) be allocated dynamically, but the code you write unfolds to atomic increment/decrement.

Comment: shared_ptr is just an object that in its destructor decrements counter in runtime. In ARC there are no additional objects, compiler inserts retain/release code at compilation time.

Comment: @mifki: Is exactly what happens in the C++ compiler.